# Load CSS and JS while the page is waiting for server

Tags: java, javascript, html, css

I am a beginner in java and web app development. Suppose to analyze & optimize JSP pages, those are taking some while to get data from server.
My question is, can we load the supporting file while the jsp is Waiting for server response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstand how HTML, JS and CSS work.

In short: the browser sends a request for a certain JSP page. This page return from the server and holds within it a number of link tags referring to the CSS and JS for the file. The browser parses this page and sees that it needs extra resources in order to properly use the page. So it sends another request to the server for the CSS and JS.

Because of this, it is impossible for the browser to know in advance what CSS and JS the JSP page would need, because these are determined by the contents of the page itself.

However, that does not mean that you are out of luck. the first page will always need to load it afterwards, but it is possible to load the CSS and JS for the other pages in advance through the explanations on [Pre-loading external files (CSS, JavaScript) for other pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1059793/pre-loading-external-files-css-javascript-for-other-pages). I have not tried these methods myself, but they seem valid.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understand you correctly, why don't you just load the CSS/JS files and fire your other function when that's done? I'm not quite sure why you'd want that, though.